# Blink Issues in Jquery Fancy Popupbox Content Click

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have used jquery fancy popup box in my site.I have issues in popup box.
Whenever i click the content on the popup box the popupbox is blinking.

below are my code which is i have tried in my local.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin 
        {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {          
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="fancybox">Test Content</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Any Help Much Appriciation.
Thanks All,

Comment: I have solved my issues after long analysis. i will post my answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a link to your page?

It's probably your `box-shadow` property. It's not supported without a prefix in some browsers, so removing it or adding the `-moz` and `-webkit` markup as well should correct the issue.

```
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;            
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have solved my issues after deep analysis & implementing various functionality

below code are solved my issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - Fancy jQuery Lightbox Alternative | Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>   

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {          
                $(".fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
             });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
        <h1>fancyBox</h1>

    <a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" style="display:none">Inline</a>

    <div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
        <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```